# Why did my answer suddenly get +100

Tags: support, reputation

My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275964/moving-an-object-in-elliptical-path/30306216#30306216) suddenly has a little blue +100 next to it, and my reputation jumped accordingly.

What was this was for?

Comment: You won a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Comment: Winning a bounty without even knowing it. That's pretty badass...

Comment: Haha! To be fair, I probably noticed it had a bounty when I answered and subsequently forgot.

Comment: If you hover over the `+100`, then it would have told you, also: http://i.imgur.com/rxD4j8s.png

Comment: I tried that - It didn't, but perhaps I didn't wait long enough as it's there now.

Comment: Let's be honest...you just wanted to show off :P

Comment: Community bounty -- that mean the user that granted the bounty deleted their account?

Comment: @Yakk It means it was auto awarded

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone awarded your answer a bounty of 100 points which is what the +100 on the post. This cost the person 100 rep which was given to you as a reward for your answer above the standard +10 for upvoting an answer.